# Docker Images Hierarchy

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to check what image is a parent of my given Docker image (FROM with image layer it was created). How can I retrieve this information?

I tried do that through

```
docker images -t
```

but this flag is deprecated in new Docker versions. Is there any reliable source of such an info?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see tree view of docker images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454679/how-to-see-tree-view-of-docker-images)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

docker tree was deprecated before any good replacement was proposed (see the debate in [PR 5001](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5001))

This is currently externalized to [`justone/dockviz`](https://github.com/justone/dockviz).

```
 alias dockviz="docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock nate/dockviz"
```

> Image info is visualized with lines indicating parent images:

```
dockviz images -d | dot -Tpng -o images.png
```

> as a tree in the terminal:

```
$ dockviz images -t
└─511136ea3c5a Virtual Size: 0.0 B
  |─f10ebce2c0e1 Virtual Size: 103.7 MB
  | └─82cdea7ab5b5 Virtual Size: 103.9 MB
  ...
```

Comment: it should be noted that with recent versions of docker / dockviz, output is full of ```<missing>  Virtual Size: xyz MB ``` which reduces the usefulness of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use dockerfile-from-image from https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image, it will create a Dockerfile, which first line will be `FROM xxx`