# Docker image layers tree

Tags: docker

In some manual I found next option:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-13:~$ sudo docker images --tree
├─f502877df6a1 Virtual Size: 2.489 MB Tags: busybox-1-export:latest
└─511136ea3c5a Virtual Size: 0 B
  └─bf747efa0e2f Virtual Size: 0 B
    └─48e5f45168b9 Virtual Size: 2.489 MB
      └─769b9341d937 Virtual Size: 2.489 MB
        └─227516d93162 Virtual Size: 2.489 MB Tags: busybox-1:latest
```

But in my:

```
# docker -v
Docker version 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3
```

I have no `--tree` option for `images`:

```
# docker images --tree
flag provided but not defined: --tree
See 'docker images --help'.
```

How can I see something like this tree?

Only using tools like `[dockviz][1]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see tree view of docker images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454679/how-to-see-tree-view-of-docker-images)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--tree` option was removed. Instead you can do (as you mention):

```
$ docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock nate/dockviz images -t
```

For more information, see https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5001

Answer (score 7):

This is the alternative you may use

```
docker history {image_name}
```

The sample output like this:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d120321c2b3f        11 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 443                   0B
4340c5fa6a72        11 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 80                    0B
8f35732293d9        11 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:84bfba8bd4750004…   1.68kB
```

I got from this link like previous answer https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5001 :)