# Tool to view tree of docker image layers

Tags: docker

Is there any way to look the layers of a set of docker images in a tree fashion? It will help examine if any siblings are serving the same purpose and one can be replaced with the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see tree view of docker images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454679/how-to-see-tree-view-of-docker-images)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier one used to be able to do this using `docker images --tree`. However that is no longer available in the latest versions of docker.

[Here is an external tool that can help achieve the same visualization](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-images-tree-visualization)

Comment: I tried the external tool. The tree view does not show the IDs and Tags for all the non-leaf layers.


├─<missing> Virtual Size: 7.3 MB

│ └─<missing> Virtual Size: 7.3 MB

│   └─4ea294712533 Virtual Size: 7.3 MB Tags: nate/dockviz:latest



My docker version is:
$ docker -v

Docker version 1.12.6, build d5236f0